# How to use install django_debug_toolbar

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run django_debug_toolbar
I followed the instructions at:
https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
I also saw several YouTube videos, this should be working.

Here's the code
*urls.py*

```
import debug_toolbar
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

*settings.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I tried to install django_debug_toolbar, but it gives a 404

Comment: _I tried to install django_debug_toolbar_ Show us the exact command you used to install it, and the exact error output.

Comment: Bear in mind you are not going to /__debug__  as a URL. You can just visit your normal django site and the toolbar will appear as a sidebar on the right.

Comment: @SamSparx I know I won't use /__debug__ as a URL, I removed that line and the toolbar does NOT appears on the right

Comment: You still need the line in your urls file,  it's just not a page you visit.  Sorry if i was unclear, just making sure as you had mentioned a 404